# Stuck in Stargazer on Linux

Tags: transactions, wallets

I have a few hundred XLM in my Stargazer 1.7.0 wallet on kubuntu 18.04 Linux. When I try to send any amount to another address, I get "No payment options found".'

How do I get my funds somewhere that works?

The address I'm trying to send to is GD3WCAP...FROZ (middle removed in this post).
I know my 24 word seed.

I installed the Solar wallet on my notebook and on my phone, but couldn't see how to restore my balance in it with any seed information I could see in Stargazer.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the Stargazer Github:

> All private keys are stored in localStorage, encrypted or not. Within
> the app, key decryption and transaction signing all take place inside
> the Keychain service in app/core/services/keychain.js. The only time
> an unencrypted private key leaves that service is when an account is
> being exported and you're not using password protection.
>
> All transactions go through the same steps of being displayed for
> review before being signed and submitted.

https://github.com/future-tense/stargazer#security

After you got the secret key:

1. Go to https://accountviewer.stellar.org/
2. Transfer XLM to your new wallet or merge it using Stellar.expert's
   account merge tool:
   https://stellar.expert/demolisher/public