# Stargazer Wallet v. 1.5.3

Tags: wallets

My XLM are stored in Stargazer Wallet v. 1.5.3 which I cannot unlock. I can see my Lumens but can't remove them. Is this wallet still viable?

Comment: This might help? https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/stuck-in-stargazer-on-linux

Comment: Just a heads up, Stack Exchange is mostly for questions with a development focus. In the future I'd refer you to our public Keybase team (https://keybase.io/team/stellar.public) or Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/) for this type of question!